# how to change specific text by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, replace

i have this html code:

```
<label class="checkbox" id="check_rem0">
    Checkbox
    <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="form_checkbox_0">
</label>
```

is there a way to replace only the text in the label, `Checkbox` in my case, withowt removing/replacing the input?

if i do `$('.checkbox').text('Anoteher Checkbox')` i will get:

```
<label class="checkbox" id="check_rem0">
    Anoteher Checkbox
</label>
```

Also, i don't necessarily know what text will be there.

Comment: You could get the html with .html and then replace it, but you'll lose any events or data stored on the checkbox. Probably better to resort to native javascript on this one, select the node directly and change it.

Comment: `html` seems to have the same effect

Comment: Not if you use it correctly. `$(".checkbox").first().html($(".checkbox").first().html().replace("Checkbox","Another Checkbox"));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't nest your input inside your label. Associate the two with `<label for="form_checkbox_0">`. That way you can manipulate the text as much as you want.

```
<label class="checkbox" id="check_rem0" for="form_checkbox_0">
    Checkbox
</label>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="form_checkbox_0">
```

Comment: for some reason jquery generate it like that: `var checkbox = $("<label/>", {text: "Checkbox"}).appendTo(checkbox_span);

$("<input/>", {type: "checkbox"}).appendTo(checkbox);`

Comment: Can you add your form generation code to the question? That certainly complicates the issue. That said, you can change `appendTo` to `insertAfter` so that it doesn't get inserted inside, but rather after, the label.

Comment: You should also switch the order of how you are appending objects to make sure adding to the live DOM is the LAST action.

Comment: +1 I totally agree. If you need to be WCAG compliant you shouldn't nest your input like @Mathletics said. See also http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F68.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#check_rem0').html('Another text <input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="form_checkbox_0">');
```

OR more correctly:

```
var a = $('#check_rem0').html();
b = a.replace('Checkbox', 'Another text');
$('#check_rem0').html(b);
```

Comment: i was thinking about this solution, but i don't know the text to be replaced

Comment: you dont know or you dont want ? you said "is there a way to replace only the text in the label". I works, i tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru21/dCSRy/

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'for' parameter in the label = to the id of your input element.

```
<label for="form_checkbox_0" class="checkbox_0_label>Checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="form_checkbox_0">
```

Then your JS:

```
$('.checkbox_0_label').text('Another Checkbox')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<label class="checkbox" id="check_rem0" for="form_checkbox_0">
    Checkbox
</label>
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="form_checkbox_0">
```

with that as your HTML, you can just do the following:

```
$("#check_rem0").text("Another checkbox");
```

Answer (score -2):

In general, whenever I have specific text to replace, I wrap it in a `<span>` with an ID and change the text of the span instead.

For example:

```
...
<h1>This is a heading with some <span id="change">embedded text</span> I'd like to change </h1>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

         $("#change").html("changed text");
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: will concede that this is not a good solution for the problem referenced in the question content - but think it answers the title well.

Comment: This does not answer OPs question, it avoids it.

Comment: It both answers the specific question referenced in the text and the more generic question referenced in the title.  Anyone should be able to infer from my response that the OP could easily wrap the text in a `<span>` to isolate it and change just the text that way.  In what way does this *avoid* the question?

Comment: No, it describes how you perform a similar task. In an aggregate solution as suggested by OPs use of label, input and suggestion that there will be multiple checkboxes, this avoidance of the actual problem will result in a very unclean cluttered implementation.

Comment: This also results in non-semantic markup, for those that care about that. (I do.)

Comment: I apologize, then.  I was under the impression people sometimes browsed stackoverflow looking for answers to questions that may be similar but not identical to the OP.  In this case, I figured a question titled `how to change specific text by using jquery` would be browsed by many people looking to do just that - not always in the context of a form label containing both text and an input.